# Ubuntu 12.04 unstable Display, Flickering

Tags: 12.04, display

I use Ubuntu 12.04.
The Text character on my screen while on the Internet s too small, so I decided to adjust the display to give larger characters. This caused the screen to become very unstable, once I am logged it the screen begins to flicker. I am now using the guest login.
How can I read just the display to first make it stable and secondly to have larger text characters?
Thanks in anticipation,

Elton.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be Gnome-Tweak-Tool, also known in the software center as "Advanced Settings". Now you may use this to change the font size affecting the software center, however unfortunately all other applications as well. A recommended way to preform the font change would be to open the settings, change the font size, and then when done with the software center, return it to it's original form, or however you prefer it. If you can't get the application from the software center, due to the small size of the font just paste the following into your terminal -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Or, click the button below to install for Ubuntu!

[image: Install via the software center]

Here is what Advanced Settings should appear as, simply click the font size next to the default font to make changes.

[image: Tweak Tool]

Well, you don't really want to mess with the other settings I'm assuming, (Graphics Drivers, or Screen Resolution) But, just to voice other solutions, you could start by seeing if this is the graphics driver, I personally use the open source one because I have no other choice than binary blobs, or the screen resolution could be toned down to make the text appear larger...

Now, as if this wasn't already long enough, [Mijyn](https://askubuntu.com/users/16913/mijyn) here wrote a tutorial on resetting the x configuration settings. This could also fix screen flickering. To start, we want to:

Press "*Ctrl + Alt + F3*"

By doing this, you're opening a virtual console, the appearance may look like DOS, but essentially it's a terminal window, gone full screen with root access. It should ask you to log in, with your password. Now the password will not appear in the window, but don't worry, it's still registering.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo rm -f xorg.conf*
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service gdm stop
sudo service kdm stop
sudo service lxdm stop
sudo service xdm stop
sudo service wdm stop
sudo Xorg -configure
[ -f xorg.conf* ] && sudo mv xorg.conf* /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Now while this seems like a lot, you can copy and paste this into the virtual console, remember, the paste function when in terminal is "*Ctrl + Shift + V*" instead of the common "*Ctrl + V*" used pretty much everywhere else.

You'll now want to restart the computer. You can regain access to the desktop using "*Ctrl + Alt + F7*". This should reset the X configuration.

If you would like to view MiJyn's work, it is linked [here.](http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/quick-and-easy-way-to-fix-x11-issues/)

Hope some of this can be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial a long time ago that might fix your issue (can't guarantee it though): http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/quick-and-easy-way-to-fix-x11-issues/

I can't really copy the contents here as it would require copying the whole post here (and I don't want to do that, for relatively obvious reasons)